# Change alpha mask when texture changes on same SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode, texture-atlas

I have two functions that help me show different animations on my SKSpriteNode, but I need the alpha mask of this Sprite to change whenever the texture changes and I cannot seem to find a way to do it.

```
var atlasAnimation = [SKTexture]()


func loadAnimation() {
    let spriteAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "atlasImages)")

    for index in 1...spriteAtlas.textureNames.count{
        let imgName = String(format: "atlasImages%01d", index) //different images that I need with their respective alpha mask
        atlasAnimation += [spriteAtlas.textureNamed(imgName)]
    }

}

func runAnimation() {
    animationNode = self.childNode(withName: "spriteWhatever") as? SKSpriteNode
    if (animationNode != nil) {
        let animation = SKAction.animate(with: atlasAnimation, timePerFrame: 0.1)
        let forever = SKAction.repeatForever(animation)
        animationNode?.run(forever)
    }
}
```

I've been searching a bit and found out how to do the alpha mask thing with code instead of the checkbox on Xcode’s sidebar (which only helps setting the alpha mask with that one texture) and I've found out how to do it with a normal SKTexture. But for this animation I need a [SKTexture] and it just won´t work overriding the normal physicsBody texture atribute, since it expects a SKTexture argument and not a [SKTexture].

```
animationNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: atlasAnimation, size: atlasAnimation.size()) 
//so atlasAnimation can't be placed here in "texture"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify: you want to create an SKPhysicsBody for this animating Sprite where the shape of the body changes with the animation, based on the alpha channel of each frame in the animation?

Comment: OK, then you cannot do that directly. An SKPhysicsBody has a fixed shape that cannot itself be animated. You can of course rotate or scale an object that has an SKPhyiscsBody and the body will accommodate those changes, but the actual shape will remain the same (just rotated or scaled). If shape changing is really what you need it would have to be done this in code - i.e. create a series of separate SKPhysicsBodies, each based on the alpha of the animation frames, and apply them to your shape as it changes frame!

Comment: Yes, I want to do it in code. The current alpha mask was enabled via checkbox just to show you what I need. But I think the problem will persist even if I create different SKPhysicsBodies, since I will still need to use my atlasAnimation as "SKTexture"  of my "animationNode". And since that SKPhysicsBody atribute expects a normal SKTexture, it won't work, right?

Comment: I am probably misunderstanding the problem but: to do this programatically (and that sounds complex to me, but if it is what you really need) you will need a separate SKPhysicsBody for each SKTexture in your atlas - so loop through the atlas, reading each texture in turn and create each SKPhysics body in turn, using the alpha in the texture. I am of course assuming that your textures have a transparent background - but then why wouldn't they?